# wurstmeister/kafka Volume to bind ? - Docker

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-volume

quick question about data persistence ; usually in a dockerhub page you get the volume to bind in order to persist data when the docker is removed. 
But in this case it is not mentionned ? https://hub.docker.com/r/wurstmeister/kafka/

For exemple in the ches/kafka image : https://hub.docker.com/r/ches/kafka/
It is mentionned :
[image: ches kafka volume to bind]

So my question is : What are the volume to bind inside the wurstmeister/kafka to persist data ? (Might be a dumb question :) )

Good day every one

Comment: This isn't really a programming question and doesn't quite seem like it's on-topic for SO.  You might be able to find a hint if you look at the Dockerfile linked from the Docker Hub page you cite, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To find the informations I went inside the Dockerfile tab : https://hub.docker.com/r/wurstmeister/kafka/~/dockerfile/

And I saw the line VOLUME ["/kafka"]

So I assumed it was that. And it was.